# Есть ли возможность обнаружить используется ноутбук или стационарный компьютер?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Знаю что в php Есть возможность  понять это мобильный телефон или нет,
есть ли возможность обнаружить это ноутбук  или стационарный компьютер ?

Comment: Нет. Да и первое тоже не очень гарантированно

Comment: Может на уровне apache или nginx  можно что-то сделать ?

Comment: Кажется вас надо почитать как работает протокол http

Comment: По какому признаку? Если у вас есть база айпи и данные какой комп сидит на этом айпи - тогда можно.

Comment: это все для статистики и нужно приблизительно понять,
Правильно ли использовать   screen resolution  или  другой user agent параметр

Comment: @a_mine никакого screen resolution в UA нет. Можно попробовать на JavaScript посмотреть на наличие батарейки, но это не точно